# Is there a way to change the HTML Error Code, if the permitted URL is too long?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, xmlhttprequest

We got the following problem:

I am currently developing a web server implementing a specific API. The association behind that API provided specific test cases I'm using to test my implementation.

One of the test cases is:

> 5.3.2.12 Robustness, large resource ID
> This test confirms correct error handling when sending a HTTP request with a very long location ID as URL parameter.

The url its calling looks something like this:
https://localhost:443/api/v2/functions/be13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005ebe13789-1f1e-47d0-8f8a-000000000005

Basically the tests checks, if my server responds with the correct error code if the URL is too long. (At the time of writing it is testing for Errorcode 405, but I already asked them if it shouldn't be 414)

I'm developing the server in Asp.Net 6 and it always returns Bad Request 400 in the testcase.
I don't seem to find a place to change the handling for this behaviour and I am not even sure, if I can, or if the IIS is blocking the request even before it reaches my server. I activated logging in IIS, but the request does not show in the logfile in inetpub/logs/LogFiles.

My question would be, if it is possible to tell IIS to return a different error code in this case, or if it is even possible to handle the error in my application.

What I tried:

- Activating IIS Logs to see if the request is even passed to my site. (It did not)
- Tried adding Filters to my Controller to see if I can catch an Exception
- Checked, if Development Error Sites are called.
- Breakpoints in existing middlewares are not reached.

EDIT:
I am now pretty sure now, that the request never reaches my application.
It is possible to reproduce the error by using the default site the IIS generates on windows. Just copy the whole path from above into a browser with the host http://localhost will also just produce the error 400

EDIT 2:
As @YurongDai pointed out, I tried activating failed request tracing for my IIS Site. I used the default path \logs\FailedReqLogFiles.
The folder was created, but no file is written, when I'm opening the URL above in my browser.

[image: Activation of failed request tracing]

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, the best way is to use failed request tracking, it will provide the key error and warning, which will help you to identify the problem.
This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error:
https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I activated the fail request tracing, but no file gets written

Answer (score 0):

IIS Error 400 occurs when the server is unable to process a request sent to a web server. The most common cause of Bad Request error 400 is an invalid URL, but it can happen for other reasons as well. To resolve IIS Error 400, first make sure that you have entered the URL correctly, typos or disallowed characters in the URL are the most common causes of Bad Request errors. If the error persists after verifying the URL, please clear your browser's cache, DNS cache, and cookies and try again.

1. Clear your browser's cookies.
2. Clear your browser's cache.
3. Clear your DNS cache.(Execute the following command in the command prompt window: `ipconfig /flushdns`)

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. I don't want to resolve the error. This test in the api expects an error response for the URI in my question. The problem is my server sends an 400 and not an 405